# Javascript / jQuery UI: Changing element img src from an array of images based on current img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, image

I have a canvas element containing an image, which is initially a Green Square. I'm trying to change the displayed image based on the input from two sets of jQuery UI radio buttons: the first set allows the user to select a colour and has 3 options (Red/Green/Blue), and the second set allows the user to select a shape (Circle/Square).

My Javascript code declares an array of images, one of which is then assigned to display in the canvas element when a button option is checked, like so:

```
var images = new Array();

images[0] = new Image();
images[0].src = '../../../media/images/Red-Circle.png';

images[1] = new Image();
images[1].src = '../../../media/images/Red-Square.png';

images[2] = new Image();
images[2].src = '../../../media/images/Green-Circle.png';

images[3] = new Image();
images[3].src = '../../../media/images/Green-Square.png';

images[4] = new Image();
images[4].src = '../../../media/images/Blue-Circle.png';

images[5] = new Image();
images[5].src = '../../../media/images/Blue-Square.png';


$(function () {
    $("#colour").buttonset();
    $("#shape").buttonset();
});

$('#red').click(function () {
    if ($('#red').is(':checked')) {
        $("#container #image img").attr("src", images[1].src);
    }
});

$('#green').click(function () {
    if ($('#green').is(':checked')) {
        $("#container #image img").attr("src", images[3].src);
    }
});

$('#blue').click(function () {
    if ($('#blue').is(':checked')) {
        $("#container #image img").attr("src", images[5].src);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="image">
          <img src="media/images/Green-Square.png" />
     </div>
</div>

<form>
     <div id="colour">
          <input type="radio" id="red" name="radio">
          <label for="colour1">Red</label>
          <input type="radio" id="green" name="radio" checked="checked">
          <label for="colour2">Green</label>
          <input type="radio" id="blue" name="radio">
          <label for="colour3">Blue</label>
     </div>
</form>
<form>
     <div id="shape">
          <input type="radio" id="circle" name="radio">
          <label for="circle">Circle</label>
          <input type="radio" id="square" name="radio" checked="checked">
          <label for="square">Square</label>
     </div>
</form>
```

I've only got as far as being able to select the colour. When it comes to selecting the shape, I want to change the displayed image to retain the previous choice of colour (so that for example, if Red was the currently selected colour and the user then selected Circle, the image displayed would change to a Red Circle and not a Green or Blue Circle). Conversely, if the user selected the shape first and THEN selected a colour, I want the displayed image to retain the choice of shape.

I have a vague idea that the solution might be to do with adding 1 or subtracting 1 from the array index based on what the current index is - but I have no clue how to implement this. I'm relatively new to JS so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is `buttonset()` ?

Comment: Could you provide a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Rayon Buttonset is a jQuery UI widget "providing a visual grouping for related buttons" - so allowing the colour and shape options to be grouped together into 2 sets of radio buttons. https://api.jqueryui.com/buttonset/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an plunker for what you are trying to do.

https://plnkr.co/edit/jMvjJCxHZzr9dxw5B6RR?p=preview

the function you will require are

```
$('#circle').change(function () {
if ($('#circle').is(':checked')) {


    var a = jQuery.grep(images, function( n ,i) {
      if ( n.src == $("#container #image img").attr("src") )
      return i;
    })[0];

    var index = images.indexOf(a);

    $("#container #image img").attr("src", images[index-1].src);
}
```

});

```
    $('#square').change(function () {
    if ($('#square').is(':checked')) {
   var a = jQuery.grep(images, function( n ,i) {
      if ( n.src == $("#container #image img").attr("src") )
      return i;
    })[0];

    var index = images.indexOf(a);

    $("#container #image img").attr("src", images[index+1].src);
}
```

The color select button logic is not correct as well please use this logic  there as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. Small issue though: if you click on one of the shape options i.e. Circle more than once, it keeps subtracting 1 from the array index and thus cycling through the images. Is there a way to prevent this so that once a button is selected, it won't change the array index if clicked on a second time?

Comment: Thanks , yeah i did notice that , i have update the plunker and the code here as well. You should use change event to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your images in an 'images' object and access them by string (ex images["RedSquare"]) I've put together a fiddle. The image links are broken but if you inspect the page you can see the src is being changed properly.

https://jsfiddle.net/5wv5ym5p/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
            <div id="image">
                <img src="media/images/Green-Square.png" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <form>
            <div class="shape-config" id="colour">
                <input type="radio" id="red" name="radio">
                <label for="red">Red</label>
                <input type="radio" id="green" name="radio" checked="checked">
                <label for="green">Green</label>
                <input type="radio" id="blue" name="radio">
                <label for="blue">Blue</label>
            </div>
        </form>
        <form>
            <div class="shape-config" id="shape">
                <input type="radio" id="circle" name="radio">
                <label for="circle">Circle</label>
                <input type="radio" id="square" name="radio" checked="checked">
                <label for="square">Square</label>
            </div>
        </form>
```

JS (needs JQuery):

```
var images = {};

images["RedCircle"] = new Image();
images["RedCircle"].src = '../../../media/images/Red-Circle.png';

images["RedSquare"] = new Image();
images["RedSquare"].src = '../../../media/images/Red-Square.png';

images["GreenCircle"] = new Image();
images["GreenCircle"].src = '../../../media/images/Green-Circle.png';

images["GreenSquare"] = new Image();
images["GreenSquare"].src = '../../../media/images/Green-Square.png';

images["BlueCircle"] = new Image();
images["BlueCircle"].src = '../../../media/images/Blue-Circle.png';

images["BlueSquare"] = new Image();
images["BlueSquare"].src = '../../../media/images/Blue-Square.png';


$(function () {
    $("#colour").buttonset();
    $("#shape").buttonset();
});

$('.shape-config input').click(function () {
        var colourId = $("#colour input:checked").attr("id");
    var colour = $('label[for='+colourId+']').text();
    var shapeId = $("#shape input:checked").attr("id");
    var shape = $('label[for='+shapeId+']').text();
        $("#container #image img").attr("src", images[colour+""+shape].src);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why bother using arrays/indexes and storing it at all?

https://jsfiddle.net/0Lqgc3vx/

**HTML**

```
<img id="img" src="Green-Square.png" />

<form>
    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="Red">
    <label for="colour1">Red</label>
    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="Green" checked="checked">
    <label for="colour2">Green</label>
    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="Blue">
    <label for="colour3">Blue</label>
</form>

<form>
    <input type="radio" name="shape" value="Circle">
    <label for="circle">Circle</label>
    <input type="radio" name="shape" value="Square" checked="checked">
    <label for="square">Square</label>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$("input[name='colour']").change(function () {
    $("#img").attr("src", this.value + "-" + $("input[name='shape']:checked").val() + ".png");
});

$("input[name='shape']").change(function () {
    $("#img").attr("src", $("input[name='colour']:checked").val() + "-" + this.value + ".png");
});
```

Comment: Potentially elegant solution, however I inspected the fiddle page and the src is not being changed at all despite checking different buttons.

Comment: Apologies, it should work but not at my laptop now, will send over a working file when I can!

Comment: @PDTan apologies for the wait.. I believe the image source not being updated may be cause by the images not being able to be loaded - here is a link to a working example file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a65nhtlt8wqhaia/test.zip?dl=0

Comment: @PDTan Update: It may simply be the use of jQuery in the Fiddle, without importing it!